# How do I put user data in the real-time database after a user signs up, with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add the user's email and username into the real-time database once they click the signup button which triggers the signupclick() method.

```
function signupclick(){
        var user = document.getElementById("user");
        var email = document.getElementById("email");
        var password = document.getElementById("password");
        const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value);
        promise.then(cred => {
            database.ref("users/" + cred.user.uid).set({
                name: user.value,
                email: email.value
            });
        })
        promise.then(() => {
            alert("You signed up! Now login with your credentials.");
            window.location="login.html"; 
        }) 
        promise.catch(e => {
            alert(e.message);
        })
    }
```

Here is my database so far. Once the user signs up I want the name, email and the user to show up in the database.

```
{
  "users" : {
    "7kNMijKyFDVQ6WEAKMoWB5P8t2u1" : {
      "name" : "Hulk"
    },
    "N6QVhNbvOZaDGBu23tjLmIbDakA2" : {
      "name" : "Susie"
    },
    "YKaDEGXOWsOFAbgAJWYquFPrg823" : {
      "name" : "Bob"
    },
    "lok19f1PxGh7xaH30qrMH3iKpBI3" : {
      "name" : "Knight"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain properly what is problem in it ? is there any log in the console ?

Comment: I believe it is because cred.user.uid is returning credentials.(insert user id here) and not just the user's id. I don't know how to fix it

Comment: The `cred.user.uid` variable holds the UID of the newly created user account.

Comment: That is what I thought. So why won't this new user get added to my database?